# How to get rid of this lines when copying?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I didn't have these lines when copying before. It looks like I clicked some button in android studio which caused these lines to appear. How can I return it to its previous situation?

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVbmm.png)

Comment: Just, Invalidate cache & restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have enabled **Column Selection Mode** unknowingly. You can disable it by right click on any file's code editor or you can search for **Column Selection Mode** shortcut in Android studio's preferences/settings to enable or disable this.
[image: Column Selection Mode]

Comment: Glad that worked. You can accept the answer so that it can help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Go to edit and untick the option which says **column selection mode**

Column selection mode is a handy tool when you want to add the same text at multiple places (for eg adding the private or @Inject annotation at multiple places)